# How do I set the framebuffer resolution for NVIDIA on 12.04?

Tags: framebuffer

So, 12.04 x86_64 is installed and working properly. I see grub and plymouth, then lightdm, X session for Unity is good. My framebuffer resolution for TTY1-6 is 1280x1024. X is 1680x1050.

I can use fbset to manually change the fb resolution to the desired 1280x800. Then to make it stick for all future settings, I changed the resolution in /etc/default/grub and /etc/initramfs-tools/modules.  I then ran update-grub2 and  update-initramfs -u, rebooted, but it is still in 1280x1024.

Where am I going wrong?

System 12.04 (x86_64)
NVIDIA Driver Version: 295.49
fb0 modes:

U:1280x800p-60
U:640x480p-67
V:1280x1024p-75
V:1280x1024p-60
V:1024x768p-75
V:1024x768p-70
V:1024x768p-60
V:800x600p-75
V:800x600p-72
V:800x600p-60
V:800x600p-56
V:640x480p-72
V:640x480p-60
U:1280x800p-60
U:320x240p-60
U:320x400p-59
U:320x200p-59
U:1280x1024p-59
U:1024x768p-60
U:800x600p-59
U:640x480p-60
U:640x400p-59

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I missed a very obvious nomodeset in my /etc/default/grub file. I changed that to modeset. Now I have a better looking terminal.

Correct framebuffer settings for native FB resolution for my NV 550 Ti.

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash modeset video=uvesafb:mode_option=1280x800-24,mtrr=3,scroll=ywrap"