# Framebuffer in Ubuntu 12.04 (NVidia)

Tags: nvidia, grub2, framebuffer

After a new install of 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04.2, my grub menu appeared in a nice, small font in a framebuffer and when Ubuntu loaded, the logo and red/white dots were small and crisp.

I've installed packages I need and fully updated the install (but it's still 12.04, not 12.10). Now the grub framebuffer and the loading logo and in a large, blurry font.

I've read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163278/how-do-i-set-the-framebuffer-resolution-for-nvidia-on-12-04) answer, but I'm not sure if it relates to what I am experiencing... I don't have `nomodeset` in `/etc/default/grub`.

Has an update changed my grub settings? Can I just uncomment this in my `/etc/default/grub` file:

```
 #GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
```

and set it to 1680x1050 (22" LCD native resolution) and run `update-grub` to get back the nice framebuffer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this if this mode is supported. You can also check [Enabling Nvidia driver messes up splash screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6033/enabling-nvidia-driver-messes-up-splash-screen) for nice Ubuntu logo during startup.